# Python Dictionary Appending

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary like this:

```
d = { 'id' : counter, 'file': [ {'name': filename, 'uri' : 'http://localhost:8000/uploads/' + filename, 'path' : os.path.join(dirname, filename) } ] }
```

So as you can see, I am trying to make a dictionary with a ID and a FILE.
In the file I want to 'save' the information of the file itself, like the name, uri, path etc... The problem I am having right now is that the values I am getting from this dictionary is the last one.
So I am guessing that I need to use a append of some sort. But I am not sure how to do this?

Thanks for reading and helping!

Kind regards, Glenn

Comment: You could make a dict that maps each `id` of a file to this `d` dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a list of dictionaries

```
# Create an empty list at the beginning
list_of_dicts = []

# Then, for each dict you create...
d = { 'id' : counter,
      'file': [ {'name': filename,
                 'uri' : 'http://localhost:8000/uploads/' + filename,
                 'path' : os.path.join(dirname, filename) } ] }
# ... add it to your list
list_of_dicts.append(d)
```

**UPDATE:**

I missed that you had a list within your dict. If you want to append to that list instead, then just get the list from your dict by the `'file'` key:

```
# The dict, with the first file
d = { 'id' : counter,
      'file': [ {'name': filename,
                 'uri' : 'http://localhost:8000/uploads/' + filename,
                 'path' : os.path.join(dirname, filename) } ] }

# Then append all files you want to the list found in d['file']
d['file'].append({'name': some_other_filename,
                  'uri': some_other_uri,
                  'path': some_other_path})
```

Comment: Oh my, didn't think it was this easy... I kinda feel stupid now... Thank you very much for your quick & correct answer!
I am using a for loop to fill a bigger dict that seperates the different files with an ID.